# Select div that ends with a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Like this one:

`<div class="abc foo-something">`

How can I select `div` that has a class ending in `-something`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@Einacio commented correct that  `$("div[class$='-something']")` will not work for `<div class="foo-something abc">`. To select and this case you can add a second selector, with the following result:

`$("div[class$='-something'],div[class*='-something ']")`

This will select and classes that ending with -something and a space follows.

Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) for more info.

Comment: it will not select <div class="foo-something abc">