# jQuery loop through elements with class suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, each

I have a class suffix named `fadecontent` in a joomla 3.0 website, and i have to loop trough all div's that have this class suffix using the $.each() function.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class) but it seems not to work with class **suffixes**. [joomla docs: class suffix](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Class_Suffixes)

```
$('.fadecontent').each(function(i, obj) {
```

with class suffix i mean this:

```
<div class="class classSuffix">exemple</div>
<!--example in my code-->
<div class="moduletable fadecontent">content</div>
```

How to archieve this?

**EDIT:** the script is in the `<HEAD>` tag

Comment: Your use of *suffix* is ambiguous. Do you mean you want to match only *part* of a class? Otherwise, with the code you provided, `$(".fadecontent")` should match the elements you're looking for.

Comment: This question is poorly worded but I think it is a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220851/element-or-class-like-selector-for-jquery

Comment: Did you remember document.ready, including jQuery etc. as what you've got should work fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/uv20hkry/

Comment: `$('.fadecontent')` should select `<div class="moduletable fadecontent">content</div>`. Problem lies elsewhere. May be missing `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Jojo, from the link you posted it looks like you want to match an actual suffix (in the etymological sense) of a class. `filter()` into a regex match against `this.className`. Look around, there probably are lots of material dealing with this problem on the web.

Comment: You realize that what you're describing as "suffix" is in fact a way Joomla attaches classes suffixed, as in separated with a underscore, not a space? Are you sure you're getting this right ?

Comment: @SalmanA when i did this whitout class suffix, but just by using $('.section) it worked fine

Comment: @JoJo: Can you post the output of `$('.section').each(function() { console.log(this.className); })`?

Comment: @JoJo, I found a couple of questions that might interest you: [How to write a selector to find elements with a class ending with a given substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17417474/464709) and [Select div that ends with a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7046164/464709).

Comment: Ok, it seems like i messed things up while i was testing all these answers. i backed the script up, tested it again and it worked. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by class suffixes. in your example

```
<div class="moduletable fadecontent">content</div>
```

That div has both the class moduletable and fadecontent. So this should loop through all the divs with the class fadecontent

```
$('.fadecontent').each(function() { console.log('Do Something here'); });
```

If this doesn't achieve what you're looking for, can you post more of your code so we might be able to see any other errors?

Comment: see update, i added joomla docs class suffix for info. i don't get any errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, it seems like i messed things up while i was testing all these answers. i backed the script up, tested it again and it worked. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery's special selectors such as this:

```
$('[class$="yoursuffix"]')
```

It should return elements whose classes contain your suffix pattern.  You can read more about this [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: that doesn't limit it to a suffix. That'll pick up any element with `yoursuffix` anywhere in the `class` attribute.

Comment: That's the "starts-with" selector, which wouldn't make sense for a suffix. And even if you use the "ends-with" selector, it'll fail if the targeted class is not last in the list of classes.

Comment: indeed, this does not work. the suffix is at the end. but sometimes, there are multiple suffixes. still thanks ;)