# How to select element that has a certain class and has a class that ends with?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code

```
<span id="student" class="studentTrainingActive selected-for">Foo bar</span>
```

How to select it?

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7046172/2516399) I have tried to use the following code:

```
$('span[class$="TrainingActive"].selected-for').length
```

But the result is always 0.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have a minor issue with your selector.

```
class$="TrainingActive"
```

Should actually be:

```
class*="TrainingActive"
```

Resulting code:

```js
console.log($('span[class*="TrainingActive"].selected-for').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="student" class="studentTrainingActive selected-for">Foo bar</span>
```

Outputs in console:

```
1
```

**Why Use *= and not $=**

As helpfully pointed out by @Andreas, the reason that `$=` as a selector is not working is because the `class` does not end with `TrainingActive`.  Look at the `class` attribute:

```
studentTrainingActive selected-for
```

It ends with `selected-for`.

Using contains (`*=`) instead will happily match the class as required and can of course be combined with `.selected-for` as you require.

Comment: You might want to explain why the "ends with" selector is not what TO should be using (despite the requirement _"...has a class that ends with"_) and why the "contains" selector is a better option

Comment: It worked, but what's wrong with my selector? I was using `$=` to select if it ends with. You used "*=" that stands for if it contains...

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I've amended the answer to include your suggestion